# User control in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

Hey frenz I am new to Umbraco cms. And I am building site using it.Here I need to include the 
.net user control with some textboxs and submit button. But when I include the macro containing the .net user control in my templete and Run the site I got the error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Control 'ContentPlaceHolderDefault_News_2_Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

I also watch the video tutorials about the Usercontrol in Umbraco. And followed the same process but i am still getting the error.

But it works fine if i used Html textbox and buttons

So, it there any solution for it.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the control 'ContentPlaceHolderDefault_News_2_Button1' of type 'Button' is not placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
Every ASP>NET control that have attribute runat="server" must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
The solution is easy:

1. Put the form into your user control

or

1. Make template that contains server form and acts as master page. Put your user control inside that template

Comment: My experience is that it is best to not include the Form tag inside the user control as that causes some problems. You can only have one form tag per page which means only one usercontrol per page etc.